# Difference Between Orderby and GroupBy in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Question 1) I Browsed many websites and couldn't understand the clear Difference between `Group by` and`Order by` 
Could anyone help me with an Example

Question 2) A sample Query like this

For Example:- `select A.sno , A.sname from Names A;` 
 results same as below Query
`select sno , sname from Names ;`

here Why we use `A` and that Dot `A.` and what we call this concept

Help me out from these 2 Questions using Examples or Links 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

In simple words,

1. `GROUP BY` groups similar values (removing duplicates). `ORDER BY` specifies the required order of data in the result.

   **Eg:**

   suppose, if the table contains:

   ```
   id   name    mark
   1    Jacob   50
   2    Mary    60
   3    Amanda  30
   ```

   Then, `select * from tableName order by mark` gives the result:

   ```
   id   name    mark
   3    Amanda  30
   1    Jacob   50
   2    Mary    60
   ```
2. In `Names A`, we are giving an alias name (or shorter name) for easiness. It might be useful when you join multiple tables.

Answer (score 2):

In your Question 1, Group by is to group the fields with same values. It's useful in counting something. For Instance you have this table name 'Table1':

```
-----
|id |
-----
|1  |
-----
|1  |
-----
|2  |
-----
```

Using this query:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id) AS `count` FROM Table1 GROUP BY id
```

it will result in:

```
------------
|id |count |
------------
|1  |2     |
------------
|2  |1     |
------------
```

With regards to Order By, it simply sorts your data in order. Let's say you have this table named 'Table2':

```
------------
| Alphabet |
------------
| C        |
------------
| A        |
------------
| D        |
------------
| B        |
------------

`SELECT * FROM Table2 ORDER BY Alphabet` will result to:
```

---

```
| Alphabet |
------------
| A        |
------------
| B        |
------------
| C        |
------------
| D        |
------------
```

In your Question 2, 'A' is the alias given to your table Names. It's useful if you have to join so many tables (especially if they have long name). So instead of:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.* FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id
```

you have to do this:

```
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM Table1 A INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.id = B.id
```

You only have to type the real table names once and use their alias in condition. Imagine if you have to join 3 or more tables without using alias - It's a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

RIght, you should not confuse the two at all.

1) `GROUP BY` will group your results with the column you specify

- [GROUP BY - W3SCHOOLS](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Example:

```
SELECT Name, surname FROM CONTACT GROUP BY Surname
```

will  result in contacts with the same surnames being grouped (all smiths together etc)

`ORDER BY` will simply order by the specified column (from a-z for a character sort or 1-9999 for intergers)

- [ORDER BY - W3SCHOOLs](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Example:

```
SELECT A.Name, cellphone  from Contact A order by Name
```

Will order results alphabetically according to Name (BTW adding a `DESC` will reverse the results in a descending manner, `ASC` for Ascending is implied by default)

2) Then you asked about aliases, this enable you to give the table names or columns your own alias and re-use it when selecting columns from that table its usefull for long table names or when similar column names occur is multiple table names.

Example:

```
SELECT A.Name AS CustomerName, C.Name AS Company
FROM Contact A
JOIN Company C on C.contactid = A.contactid
```

(I've created aliases for the tables contact as **A**, Company **C** and re-named the similar columns from both tables with aliases as **customername**, **company**)

Does this help?

Comment: sure for this example Yes!

Answer (score 1):

ORDER BY: retrieves the data in specific order means sorted of the mentioned column. there is Ascending order and descending order of sorting. The Default one is Ascending.

Group By: Is the part of selectexpression with divide the result into subset according to the column mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

GroupBy is an integration function, after group by, you get sum amount.

OrderBy is just simple function, you still get the result you queried before, but they are 'ordered' by your choices.